# When I runserver I get this error: Django 405 error

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows, settings, http-status-code-405

> Django 405 error-page not found. when I runserver I get this error.Anybody have any clue how to fix this error? I use Windows 10, python, django.

```
[08/Apr/2023 19:54:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3710
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Apr/2023 19:54:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4697
[08/Apr/2023 19:54:40] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3959
[08/Apr/2023 19:55:17] "GET /password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3402
[08/Apr/2023 19:55:25] "POST /password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Apr/2023 19:55:25] "GET /password/reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3135
Method Not Allowed (POST): /password/reset/done/
Method Not Allowed: /password/reset/done/
[08/Apr/2023 19:55:28] "POST /password/reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

> My settings.py file looks like this

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
env_path = BASE_DIR / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', "error")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", True)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_crontab',
    'service',
    'base',
    'blog',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static_folder'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static', ]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

BASE_URL = os.getenv('BASE_URL')

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

USE_L10N = False
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'service.sendmail.mail_customer')
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
LOGIN_URL = '/users/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'service/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

CACHE_ENABLED = os.getenv('CACHE_ENABLED')

if CACHE_ENABLED:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
            'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
        }
    }
```

> and my urls.py is

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from django.urls import path
from users.apps import UsersConfig
from users.views import SigninView, SignupView, SignupSuccessView, verify_email, CustomPasswordResetView, CustomPasswordResetConfirmView, CustomPasswordResetCompleteView, CustomPasswordResetDoneView, simple_reset_password, UsersListView, user_status_change


app_name = UsersConfig.name

urlpatterns = [
    path('', SigninView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('register/', SignupView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('register/success/', SignupSuccessView.as_view(), name='register_success'),
    path('password/reset/', CustomPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password/reset/<uidb64>/confirm/<token>/', CustomPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password/reset/done/',
         CustomPasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password/reset/complete/', CustomPasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_form.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('verify/<str:token>/', verify_email, name='verify_email'),
    path('simple/reset/', simple_reset_password, name='simple_reset'),
    path('user_list/', UsersListView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
    path('user_change/<int:pk>/', user_status_change, name='user_change')
]
```

> my views is

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView, PasswordResetCompleteView, \
    PasswordResetDoneView
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, TemplateView, UpdateView, ListView
from users.forms import SigninForm, SignupForm, CustomPasswordResetForm, CustomEditUserForm
from users.models import User
from users.service import set_verify_token_and_send_mail, generate_password_and_send_mail


class UserEditProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/simple_reset.html'
    form_class = CustomEditUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:home')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user


class SigninView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
    form_class = SigninForm


class SignupView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    model = User
    form_class = SignupForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:register_success')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            set_verify_token_and_send_mail(self.object)
            self.object.is_active = True
            self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class SignupSuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/signup_success.html'


class VerifySuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/verify_success.html'


def verify_email(request, token):
    current_user = User.objects.filter(token=token).first()
    if current_user:
        now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))
        if now > current_user.token_expired:
            current_user.delete()
            return render(request, 'users/verify_token_expired.html')

        current_user.is_active = True
        current_user.token = None
        current_user.token_expired = None
        current_user.save()
        return redirect('users:login')
    return render(request, 'users/verify_failed.html')


class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'users/password_reset_form.html'
    form_class = CustomPasswordResetForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')
    email_template_name = 'users/email_reset.html'
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER


class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = 'users/reset_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')


class CustomPasswordResetDoneView(PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'users/reset_done.html'


class CustomPasswordResetCompleteView(PasswordResetCompleteView):
    template_name = 'users/reset_complete.html'


def simple_reset_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        current_user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST.get('email')).first()
        if current_user:
            generate_password_and_send_mail(current_user)
        return render(request, 'users/simple_reset.html')


def confirm_new_generated_password(request):
    current_user = User.objects.filter(email=request.GET.get('email')).first()
    current_user.password = current_user.new_password
    current_user.new_password = None
    current_user.save()
    return redirect(...)


class UsersListView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/user_list.html'


@permission_required('users.change_status')
def user_status_change(request, pk):
    current_user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    if current_user.is_superuser:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    if current_user.is_active:
        current_user.is_active = False
    else:
        current_user.is_active = True
    current_user.save()
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

> I think my problem is either in my urls.py, or my settings.py, or my views.py but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a POST request to `/password/reset/done/`. As the error suggests (405). POST method is not allowed for this url / view.

Looking at `PasswordResetDoneView` source code (Which inherits from TemplateView) it doesn't have a Post method.

So you should only send GET requests to `/password/reset/done/`.

If you need to send a POST request to the url for some reason, add a post method to `CustomPasswordResetDoneView` (Might need to add some other stuff, like form_class, etc).

Something like this

```
class CustomPasswordResetDoneView(PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'users/reset_done.html'

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        ...
```